# How to add an header view to a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

These are the steps I did to add my own view as a header:

Creating a new view:

```
class HeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Register the view inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
    self.collectionView?.register(HeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header")
```

Implementing the `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` delegate:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width:view.frame.size.width, height:100.0)
}
```

Implement the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` delegate:

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        switch kind {
        case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
            let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath) as! HeaderView
            header.setNeedsLayout()
            return header

        default:
            return UICollectionReusableView()
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't not work. My `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` and `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` are not called when running the app.

I did setup my delegates inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.collectionView?.delegate = self
```

Am I missing any step ? Or did I do something wrong ?

edit:

Forgot to mention: I am using a custom layout, not sure if this matter, but in storyboards when you choose custom layout the `Section Header` option disappears.

Comment: Just to be sure: your collection view does contain at least one section?

Comment: Yes. It has just one section. I can see my data inside, but no header.

Comment: `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` is a method of the layout delegate not the collection view delegate. Did you set the delegate of the layout too?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so, how do you do that ? I am just working with the collection view for the first time.

Comment: So I guess you use a plain UICollectionViewController. It has the following initializer: `init(collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout)`. Do you use that?

Comment: I just define it myself, because it was missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157921/discussion-between-d-mika-and-kobe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you need to configure your layout properly to get a section header displayed.

As you use a custom layout, you don't need to implement `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` at all. It's a method of the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. That's the reason it isn't called.